# HowTo? UISplitViewController TableCell Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I would like to know if it is possible to assign some kind of icon/image to the navigation table cells on the left side of the UISplitViewController in an iPad App.

e.g. an image next to row 1...

http://www.cre8ive.kr/blog/wp-content/uploads/SplitViewTest_03.png

I am trying to approach this with editing the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

method.

Here's what I got

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row +1];  
    //Let the magic happen here :D
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"deviantart_dark.png"];
    //Nothing changes :(
    [[cell imageView] setImage:image];
    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below code,

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage:imageNamed:@"deviantart_dark.png"]];
```

Comment: Tryed it and here is the result
http://mbdesigns.de/Bildschirmfoto%202011-10-28%20um%2007.39.55.png
I also tried to use a fullsized background image for the cell size but it looked the same.
I dont think that apple allows icons in the navigation of the splitviewcontroller :(

Comment: sure they do. Can u post the whole code that u used. And could u try by removing the textLabel part. Set only the background color and no text for the textLabel.

Comment: That did the job - but there's still a problem...

When I click on cell - the background disappears (so the icon/image) is invisible etc...
Is there a way to set the background for the active state of a cell?